# Cannot update spyder due to SNI warning

Tags: python, openssl, spyder

I have python 2.7.6 with spyder 2.2.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.5. I couldn't connect to Ipython console so I decide to update spyder:

```
pip install spyder --upgrade
```

It throws the following errors. The text of the top one is:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.

Full stack trace:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting spyder
  Downloading spyder-3.1.4-py2-none-any.whl (3.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.5MB 387kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: pygments>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spyder)
Requirement already up-to-date: jedi>=0.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spyder)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyflakes in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spyder)
Requirement already up-to-date: pylint in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spyder)
Requirement already up-to-date: nbconvert in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spyder)
Requirement already up-to-date: qtpy>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spyder)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyzmq in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from spyder)
Collecting numpydoc (from spyder)
  Downloading numpydoc-0.6.0.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I tried install some other packages like `ndg-httpsclient`, `urllib3[secure]` without luck. It throws exactly the same error. I cannot upgrade python itself. Can somebody help?

Note: I do have `python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev` already installed.

Comment: do you have up-to-date `pip`, `setuptools` and `requests` versions? Maybe also a good time to update python itself, 2.7.6 isn't a "current" version (released 2013...), if you want to continue using python-2, at least update to 2.7.13.

Comment: 2.7.6 is the default python for Ubuntu 14.04 and I was told not to mess with it. My `pip` is already up-to-date (9.0.1), and I have updated `requests` (to 2.14.2) and `setuptools` to the latest version. But updating spyder still have that error.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to replace your systems python. You can use `virtualenv` or `conda` to manage seperate python installations. But those were just guesses, I've never seen that error I was just eliminating possible causes (and generally it's not a bad idea to have up-to-date packages). :)

Comment: Have you done what https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning suggests? Or did you skip that step?

Comment: @jww I followed it and the `SNIMissingWarning` and `InsecurePlatformWarning` warnings disappear. However the error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my `requirements.py` has problem (as the error suggests). I don't know if it causes future harm but adding an empty string to `MARKER_EXPR()` function fixes it.

> MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR(""))("marker")